# GetUserInfoAsync returns only sub without other claims

Tags: identityserver4

Why does GetUserInfoAsync return only sub without other claims?

```
var discoveryResponse = client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync("some Authorization Url").Result;
var userInfoResponse = client.GetUserInfoAsync(new UserInfoRequest
{
    Address = discoveryResponse.UserInfoEndpoint,
    Token = token // access_token
}).Result;
```

**After signed in I have in the response 'email' but when I call GetUserInfoAsync I don't have it.** I pass to GetUserInfoAsync access_token maybe that? Because claims are in id_token but how I can return claims from GetUserInfoAsync in that case?

My code:

I have on the list of the IdentityResource 'email':

```
public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
{
    return new List<IdentityResource>
    {
        new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
        new IdentityResources.Email()
    };
}
```

In the client I have 'email' and 'AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken':

```
return new Client
{
    ClientId = clientId,
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
    RedirectUris = { "some url" },
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "some url" },
    AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,
    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
    {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        "email"
    }
};
```

I pass scopes in the SignInAsync method:

```
await _accessor.HttpContext.SignInAsync(subject, new Claim(ClaimNames.Email, email));
```

In the requested scopes I have:

```
scope: 'openid email'
```

Comment: You are right with your assumption, you have to introduce an `ApiResource` with a scope and `email` claim inside, then you will have it in your `access_token`

Comment: I have added it to ApiResource list, to client and to scopes but I still don't have it in /userinfo. In ProfileService - GetProfileDataAsync - I use: `context.AddRequestedClaims(context.Subject.Claims);`

Comment: you added it server side, but have you requested your new scope?

Comment: WOW - you have right - thx !! The important thing - the claim must be in IdentityResource and ApiResource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UserInfo endpoint requires authorization with `access_token` having at least `openid` scope, which is transformed into the `sub` claim in response. All the rest is optional. That is by the [spec](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#UserInfo).

Now let's [see](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/resources.html) how that's arranged in IdentityServer 4.
Everything related to access_token (intended to be used by APIs) is grouped into `ApiResource` configuration. That's the only place where you can configure the *API scopes* and their claims. After introducing a scope, you may add it to the list of accessible for a particular client. Then, client side you may request it explicitly. `ApiResource` configuration might look a bit messy as it has additional fields such as API credentials for Introspection endpoint access, but the constructor we need to fetch some *UseInfo* data is extremely simple:

```cs
new ApiResource("UserInfo", new []{JwtClaimTypes.Email, JwtClaimTypes.GivenName})
```

With the code above we created the ApiResource `"UserInfo"` with the scope `"UserInfo"` and a couple associated user claims.

All the same and more, from the first hand [here](https://brockallen.com/2019/02/25/scope-and-claims-design-in-identityserver/)

Comment: You also have to add: JwtClaimTypes.Email, JwtClaimTypes.GivenName to IdentityResources yes?

Comment: that's up to you. that's for identity token when you use `AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken`. and there you can use predefined claims sets such as `IdentityResources.Email()`, `IdentityResources.Profile()`